# How can I bridge an HTTP server from an interface to another in Linux?

Tags: linux-networking, bridge

In a Linux server I have an HTTP server that's available at eth1 with ip1, and I want to make it available to the network in eth2 with ip2. How can I do this?

Example: I have an http server on 192.168.1.1:80 connected to a PC's Ethernet port, eth0, and I want another machine to connect to that PC using wifi, wlan0, and access that previously mentioned server as if it was running on the PC.

Comment: What HTTP server are you using and what version is it?  Apache typically listens on all IP addresses by default.

Comment: Does it matter?